# Rails 5.2 TinyMCE Image Uploads with Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I'm using [this](https://www.techcourses.com.au/blog/how-to-build-a-kick-ass-wysiwyg) tutorial to try to facilitate image uploads using the TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor on my rails 5.2 app.

So far I have implemented all the code in the tutorial and everything works perfectly, but when I try to upload an image I get a "Got a bad response from the server" error message.

In my `heroku logs` I then get this:

```
FATAL -- : [527c4468-9ebe-475a-97a9-380bfc327aab] ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant #<Class:0x000055b6d991e020>::EditController
2020-02-22T17:34:07.814727+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you mean?  DeviseController):
```

Here is the route I'm using:

```
post '/tinymce_assets', to: 'article/edit#image_upload'
```

With these controller methods:

```
  def image_upload
    file = params[:file]
    url = upload_file(file)
      render json: {
        image: {
          url: url
        }
      }, content_type: "text/html"
  end


  private

    def upload_file(file)
      s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:ENV['AWS_REGION'])
      obj = s3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']).object('articles/images/content/' + filename(file))
      obj.upload_file(file.tempfile, {acl: 'public-read'})
      obj.public_url.to_s
    end

    def filename(file)
      file.original_filename.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.]/, '_')
    end
```

And this to initialize it:

```
<%= f.text_area :body, class: "tinymce", rows: 20, cols: 120 %>
<%= tinymce :content_css => asset_path('application.css')%>

...


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: "textarea.tinymce",  // change this value according to your HTML
    });
  });
</script>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Are the controller methods above in your `EditController`?

Comment: @SaraTibbetts They're in my `ArticlesController`.

Comment: The error seems to suggest there's a reference to an `EditController` somewhere.  Does it point to any specific line in the code?

Comment: That's coming from this line `post '/tinymce_assets', to: 'article/edit#image_upload'` but I don't know how to format the `to:` properly?

Comment: Ah okay, can you post the entirety of your `ArticlesController`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails is trying to find an `EditController` because of your route: `post '/tinymce_assets', to: 'article/edit#image_upload'`

This route suggests that the controller it should look in is `Article::EditController`.  Since you are actually looking for the `ArticlesController` you should change your route to be:

```
post '/tinymce_assets', to: 'articles#image_upload'
```

The Rails routing documentation can be helpful, specifically section 2.2 and 2.6.   https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: This is assuming your controller is `class ArticlesController < ApplicationController`

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I had to add some config variables to Heroku, but with this change I was able to get there.  Thanks!